# Socket.io emit from Express controllers

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, socket.io

I'm quite new to Node.js / Express, and I'm using it as a backend for an AngularJS app. I've looked all over StackOverflow for some help on my problem, but I can't seem to figure out how to port the suggestions to my code.

My application works as follows:

- A long running Scala process periodically sends my Node.js application log messages. It does this by posting to an HTTP API
- When the post is received, my application writes the log message to MongoDB
- The log messages are then sent in real time to the Angular client.

I am having a problem with Node's modules, as I can't figure out how to refer to the socket instance in the Express controller.

As you can see, in server.js, socket.io is instantiated there. However, I would like the controller itself, logs.js, to be able to emit using the socket.io instance.

**How can I refer to io in the controller? I'm not sure how to pass the io instance to the controller so I can emit messages?**

Here is some of the Node code:

**server.js**

```
var app = express(),
  server = require('http').createServer(app),
  io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

require('./lib/config/express')(app);
require('./lib/routes')(app);

server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on %s:%d, in %s mode', config.ip, config.port, app.get('env'));
});

io.set('log level', 1); // reduce logging

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('socket connected');
  socket.emit('message', {
    message: 'You are connected to the backend through the socket!'
  });
});

exports = module.exports = app;
```

**routes.js**

```
var logs = require('./controllers/logs'),
  middleware = require('./middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.route('/logs')
    .post(logs.create);
}
```

**logs.js**

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
 // write body of api request to mongodb (this is fine)
 // emit log message to angular with socket.io (how do i refer to the io instance in server.js)
};
```

Comment: For this pattern I used a mix between **socket.io** and Node.js **Events**. Check [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596689/using-socket-io-in-express-js-project/52103434#52103434).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a pattern based on standard JS closures. The main export in `logs.js` will not be the controller function itself, but a factory function that will accept all needed dependencies, and create the controller:

```
exports.create = function(socket) {
  return function(req, res) {
    // write body of api request to mongodb
    socket.emit();
  }
}
```

Then, when you want to use it:

```
app.route('/logs').post(logs.create(socket));
```

Since you set up your routes in a separate package, you have to use the same pattern in `routes.js` - `routes` should receive the socket to use as a parameter.

This pattern works well if you want to handle those things with DI later, or test your controllers with mock "sockets".

Comment: Thanks, you are my hero!

Comment: How do you define socket in routes.js to use it in the route as illustrated above?