# Socket io emit message to client from express controller method

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I know that usually you would have `app.js` create the socket server, and pass that instance down to your router, which in turn can pass it to controller methods. As shown here ([Socket.io emit from Express controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736065/socket-io-emit-from-express-controllers))

However, I have a controller method that needs to emit progress to any client who happens to be listening, but this method can be executed from many different routes, and other controllers, and I don't really want to have to pass a reference to `socket` around all these other parts of the app.

Is there a better way to do it?

I was thinking something like a `socketio` helper module.  The `app.js` module passes it a reference to `io`, which can be retrieved later....

*app.js*

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);    
require('./helpers/socketio').set(io);
```

*helpers/socketio.js*

```
var io=null;

exports.set = function(socketio) {
   io=socketio;
}

exports.get = function() {
  return io;
}
```

Then whenever you need it in the app..

```
var io = require('./helpers/socketio').get();
io.emit('message', {a:1, b:2});
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Clearly it could return null, which you would have to check for.  It just doesn't feel right....

Answer (score 2):

A solution that worked for me was assigning io to app as:

```
 app.io = io in app.js
```

then anywhere you have access to the app object you have a link to the socket.

example :

```
file: index.js my main routing file for authenticated users

const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');
```

... rest of the file

```
// Dashboard

router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>{

  res.render('dashboard')  //sends the dashboard page to the user

  req.app.io.emit('hello',req.user.name + ' Has Joined' ) 
 // lets every one else know that a new user has joined

})
```

Comment: [socket.io: Getting all connected sockets in Node/Express](http://blog.adeel.io/2016/02/28/socket-io-getting-all-connected-sockets-in-nodeexpress/)

Answer (score 1):

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded.

Actually, you can verify socket.io at `helper/socketio.js`.
Although you call `require()` that `socketio.js` from other files, node.js will execute code on that file only one time.

[You can look Node Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)

Comment: Yup, but how does that help with retrieving a reference to the current running socket io server?  io server is started in app.js, so I want a way to retrieve a reference to it from other modules...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Create a js file and add something like this

```
const service = {}

    const server = require('http').Server()
    const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origins: ['http://localhost:4200']
    }
});

service.inicializar = () => {
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        const idHandShake = socket.id;
        const { email } = socket.handshake.query;

        socket.join(email);

        console.log(`Conexion establecida --> ${idHandShake}`);

        //Este metodo escucha lo que envia el front y tiene la capacidad de emitir hacia otros miembros de la sala.
        socket.on('event', (res) => {
            const data = res
            console.log(data)

            //Envia un mensaje a todos los participantes del room
            socket.to(email).emit('event', data);
        })
    })
    return io;
}

service.emitEvent = async (email, mensaje) => {
    const sockets = await io.in(email).fetchSockets();
    sockets[0].emit('event', mensaje);
}
service.emitSesionIniciada = async (email, mensaje) => {
    console.log('email de session iniciada: ', email);
    const sockets = await io.in(email).fetchSockets();
    sockets[0].emit('sessionIniciada', mensaje);
}

module.exports = service;
```

you can see that Im exporting some methods on service object. You can use it later from other files just refering this one

In your server.js or app.js o whatever you run the server

```
const socket = require('./src/services/socket')---< this is refering the file you created
const io = socket.inicializar() ---> this call it just one. Initialize the server.
```

Hope this helps. Regards.